# How to set the number of ListView columns dynamically

Tags: wpf, listview

I got a window containing two usercontrols, a usercontrol with a listview and a usercontrol with some other controls.

Something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------+
| header stuff                                    |
+---------------------------+---------------------+
| usercontrol with listview | another usercontrol |
+-------------------------------------------------+
| footer stuff                                    |
+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Problem: on screens with low resolution its only possible to see around 2 of the 3 columns and you need to scroll to see the thrid column. I want to avoid the horizontal scrolling by dynamically setting whether to show 1,2 or 3 columns depending on the width. Another problem is that the names can
be very long, so the width of the items in the listview all have same width as the the longest name.

Code for listview:

```
<ListView Name="lstContacts" 
 ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Contacts}" 
 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
 ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource RoundedItem}"
 SelectionMode="Single"
 HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"    
 VerticalAlignment="Top"
 HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="3">
                <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" Text="{Binding     Path=Identifier}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                <TextBlock FontSize="16" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"     HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="3" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemsPanel>
</ListView>
```

Any ideas on how to sort this out ?

Perhaps the listview is a bad choice ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `WrapPanel` as the `ItemsPanel`:

```
<ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <WrapPanel />
</ItemsPanelTemplate>
```

Note that there is no native virtualizing WrapPanel, so this will not perform well for a large collection of items.

Answer (score 0):

since your names can be long you can :
1- use textbox having textwrapping and Max/Min Height.
2- decrease fonts size for Names.
3- put Names in a ViewBox for them to always fit. (wrap also)